# Using Amazon Book Gallery Plugins in Wordpress

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I am new to WordPress plugins. I have installed "Now Reading Reloaded" Plugin. My objective is to display bunch of books which i am reading or referring on a separate page : Books.

I have installed, Activated, Also registered the Amazon Web Services Access Key ID.

How to set the Plugin to the Books Page and make the list of books to display on that page?

Comment: Users who already asked as many questions as you did are somehow expected to have read what's off topic on this site per the [help/dont-ask]. Please go and read that up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs for the plugin. You need to use the template files (included with the plugin in the templates folder). You need to and modify the html and php to match your own theme's template files so you can use them in your own theme and have the pages look like your own theme's design.

Comment: well i just found a plugin. You can also recommend me a good plugin which does the features i expect. Thanks

Comment: I am actually searching for a good plugin which i use as Amazon Book Gallery on my page. When i say good plugin, i am looking forward with more help like docs.